Tosca Object Reference Error in Specific Tests Despite All Needed Elements Synchronization in Slim Workspace
I have several tests where I use a specific object. When I run them, both from the ExecutionList and in ScratchBook, I receive the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for that particular element. However, when my colleagues run the same tests, this issue does not occur. I'm working in a slim workspace.
I believe I have synchronized all the necessary elements—how can I ensure this? What else can I do to resolve this issue?
